# ios drive sdk | How do I check each ticket, then cancel it? e.g. if it has tag = 1, I need to cancel it

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api, google-api-objc-client

How do I check each ticket, then cancel it? e.g. if it has tag = 1, I need to cancel it.
Does the google API have a list of tickets under drive service? And how do I add a tag or similar property without changing the ticket class?

Answer (score 1):

The service object does not keep a list of outstanding tickets; your app should keep an array of the tickets.

(The [fetcher service object](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Source/Objects/GTLService.h#417) used by the API service object does have a list of outstanding fetchers, and the tickets that issued each fetcher are available via a [ticket category method](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Source/Objects/GTLService.h#594) But it's still best if your app just keeps an array of the tickets that it cares about.)

Each ticket can have [properties](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Source/Objects/GTLService.h#552) set via setProperty:forKey: and accessed with propertyForKey: